# Принцип работы rss-ленты

Tags: php, rss

Просмотрел 71 сайт,посвященный реализации `rss`. Везде одно и тоже -создать файл `rss.php`, который будет генерировать саму ленту. Пример `rss.php`

```
    <?php
    header("Content-Type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding='utf-8'?>";
    ?>    
    <rss version="2.0">
     <channel>
     <title>Название канала</title>
    <link>Адрес сайта</link> и Т.Д.
```

Это все хорошо, но нигде не сказано, что ДЕЛАТЬ дальше. Если файл привязать к ссылке, то в браузере просто будет отображаться `xml`-документ. Какова реализация самой отправки на `email` пользователя? Что отправлять функцией `mail`? Готовые скрипты не интересуют. Только принцип работы.

Comment: А причем тут email?

Comment: @fStrange, а куда по-вашему отправятся обновленные новости с сайта?

Comment: @Deus, как ни странно, новости по почте пользователь получает, подписавшись на рассылку новостей по почте. RSS к этому не имеет ни малейшего отношения. Вы можете отправлять e-mail при обновлениях, которые отражаются в RSS, но это будет масло масляное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSS к почте не имеет отношения, как уже верно ответили. Это формат общения rss-клиента и вашего сайта. rss-клиент - это может быть M2 в опере или Google reader, для примера. Чтобы узнать что такое rss надо им один раз по крайней мере самому воспользоваться.

Когда пользователь в соответствующей программе подписывается на rss сайта, то rss-клиент периодически опрашивает адрес (тот самый вами созданный rss.php) и, если появилось что-то новое, оповещает пользователя.

Никаких писем никому не рассылается, у вас путаница в понятиях.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, почему когда я жму на любом сайте на иконку rss - у меня в браузере выводится xml-документ и больше ничего?

Comment: Потому что не установлена программа-клиент RSS. Или не настроен браузерный клиент, как, например, оперный.

Answer (score 2):

RSS сам по себе никак не ответственен за отправку каких-либо email'ов, отображению новостных лент и приготовке кофе. Если вы хотите рассылать обновления пользователям, они **сами из своих клиентов**, должны *подписаться* на вашу RSS-ленту. Либо вы должны самостоятельно отправлять электронные письма.

RSS является сервисом, *предоставляющим* данные по запросу. Для его работы необходим ещё и *потребитель*, который эти данные поглотит. Пользователь должен самостоятельно *подписаться* на вашу RSS-ленту. Для этого можно использовать, например, тот же *Google Reader*.

Для *рассылок* существуют *специальные сервисы* вроде [SmartResponder](http://smartresponder.ru/) или [UniSender](http://www.unisender.com/ru/). Их роботы будут автоматически читать вашу RSS-ленту и рассылать обновления.

Кроме того, вам ещё и не придётся сталкиваться с такими явлениями, как **бан** в Google, или строптивые почтовые сервера *Mail.Ru*, не желающие принимать почту. И ещё с кучей назойливых мелочей, связанных с рассылками.

Comment: @khaos, это круто. Пишу все сам - в БД есть ящики подписанных на рассылку юзеров к примеру. Есть вышеуказанный файл rss.php( или rss.xml). Как этот файл отправляется на почту юзеру?

Comment: @Deus Если вкратце — никак. RSS является сервисом, _предоставляющим_ данные по запросу. Для его работы необходимо ещё и _потребитель_, который эти данные поглотит.

Comment: @khaos, юзер видит на почте новое письмо-рассылку. Открывает его, а там - матерь божья! - последние новости с того света! Как это реализовать на php?

Comment: @Deus, как я и сказал, самостоятельной отправкой письма с новостями пользователю. Например, с помощью `mail`. Но при этом вы натолкнётесь на такое количество треша, угара и расчленёнки, что проще использовать сервисы рассылки.